# Python - Optional list values - A more pythonic way?

Tags: python, list, optional-values

I'd like to know if there is a more pythonic way to declare a list with an optional value?

```
title = data.get('title')
label = data.get('label') or None

if label:
   parent = [title, label]
else:
   parent = [title]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just filter out the falsey values — `parent = [i for i in parent if i]`.

Comment: No, because you probably shouldn't be using a list in the first place

Comment: Do you really want `data.get('label') or None`? That will turn `0`, `[]`, `False`, etc. into `None`. Since the later code is treating any false-y `label` the same, there was no reason to convert them all to `None`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @abarnert ~ Does '' also get converted to None?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work in Python 2.

```
title = data.get('title')
label = data.get('label')

parent = filter(None, [title, label])
```

Use `list(filter(...))` in Python 3, since it returns a *lazy* object in Python 3, not a list.

Or `parent = [i for i in parent if i]`, a list comprehension which works in both versions.

Each snippet filters out the *falsish* values, leaving you only the ones that actually contain data.

Comment: +1 for Py2 vs. Py3 differences, and showing the list comprehension equivalent that works in both, and explaining what it does.

Comment: Accepted this because of the explanation of  Python2 ~ Python3 difference. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could even merge this all into one line:

```
parent = [data[k] for k in ('title', 'label') if data.get(k)]
```

Or, if you only want to skip *missing* values, not all falsish values:

```
parent = [data[k] for k in ('title', 'label') if k in data]
```